# How exactly does Podio API rate limit work?

Tags: podio

According to https://developers.podio.com/index/limits the "Rate limits are per user per API key."

In our experience this seem to be true for apps as well.

What I am looking for is a confirmation on how API rate limit works.

Are all of these statements true?

- Rate limits are per user and app authentification per API key
- When the rate limits are hit in one API key for one spesific user or app authentification, the other user/app authentifications remains unaffected

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It has worked this way for me, and I have had scripts that have hit the rate limit before.